# Подскажите как реализовать кривую

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как такую кривую на 2 блока.

Comment: если у меня нету псд файла или каких либо картинок, интересует просто создание кривой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью CSS свойства `clip-path` вы можете создать любую нужную вам ограниченную область, которая будет определять, какая часть элемента должна быть видимой. Вот вам пример:

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0;} body {background: tan;}

section {display: flex; background: tan;}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 7%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.text {
  width: 40%; padding: 5%; background: aliceblue;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 7%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

img {display: block; max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cbs-vao.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Библ.-74_анонс_06.02.20_мы-с-Пушкиным-знакомы-с-детства.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>А.С. Пушкин</h1>
    <p><br>Я помню чудное мгновенье:<br>Передо мной явилась ты,<br>Как мимолетное виденье,<br>Как гений чистой красоты.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался по большому счету, отмечу коммент как лучший.